# what is the name of this fish?

Tags: species-identification, species, ichthyology

[image: it is one of the fish in my aquarium and i dont know the name of this fish. both the fish are of the same species but the colors of these two fishes are very different. [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQgGb.jpg)
fishes are of length 2 to 3 inches.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Tank fish are pets so I suggest you search [the Pets SE for an identification.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) There's little biological interest in pet identifications, if you want to leave this question here adding geographical information may avoid some downvotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like Jewel Fish, a cichlid that has been kept for a long time. Hemichromus bimaculatus , native to west Africa a bit different from "African Cichlids" which are from east Africa. Source : Exotic Aquarium Fishes by W. T. Innes ( the guy neon tetras are named after), 1937 ; But I don't think you can find it online .